# Certain section has wrong sized text and no margin

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a webpage for a class (yes I know, flay me alive now) but a certain part of my page isn't formatting correctly. I've re-typed, re-written, and looked through my code, but for the life of me, I cannot determine why it's not formatting correctly.

Basically, all of the text in the wrapper should have a 10px margin on either side and only this section doesn't. The rest has the same style applied to it, has the same rules, and no noticeable differences, and works fine. But this section is the wrong sized text and has no 10px margin on either side.

The code is as follows. I have it in a div wrapper with a style sheet attached:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-overline-color: #356618;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 10 10 10 10;
  background-color: #DAEAD0;
  font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFA500;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  background-color: #FFA500;
}

.custom {
  color: #836145;
  font-size: 125%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #8C8C8C;
  margin=10px;
}

.custom2 {
  color: #356618;
  font-size: 87.5%
}
```

```html
<h2 class="custom">Description</h2>
<p class="custom2">
  Kumquats have been called "the little gold gems of the citrus family". They are believed to be native to China and were included in the genus Citrus until about 1915 when Dr. Walter T. Swingle set them apart in the genus Fortunella (in honor of the British
  horticulturist, Robert Fortune who introduced the kumquat to Europe in 1846). Kumquats have a very distinctive taste. It is the only citrus fruit that can be eaten "skin and all." The peel is the sweetest part and can be eaten separately. The pulp contains
  the seeds and juice, which is sour. When eaten together, you get a sweet and sour taste which is unlike anything else. The seeds, however, should not be eaten. They are similar to the seed of the orange and have a distinctive green color. The seeds
  also contain pectin, which can be removed by boiling for use in making jams and jellies.</p>

<h2 class="custom">Varieties</h2>
<p class="custom2">
  There exist several cultivars of kumquat; however, only four of them are grown widely for their fruits.
  <ul class="custom2">
    <li>Nagami (Fortunella margarita): The fruit is oval and is the most common variety grown inside the USA. It features a smooth, light yellow peel and has a tart flavor.
    </li>
    <li>Marumi (Fortunella japonica): The fruit is round, and has a distinctive sweet taste and pleasant flavor.
    </li>
    <li>Meiwa (Fortunella crassifolia): It is round in shape, and larger than other verities. It is popular in Japan by name ninpo or neiha kinkan.
    </li>
    <li>Hong Kong Wild (Fortunella hindsii): They are the smallest sized kumquats.
    </li>

</p>
```

Comment: `margin = 10px;` ??

Comment: You made some typos in your `CSS` file, especially regarding `margin`
I think you should take @cske advice **;)**

Comment: @lynnrhyann is my answer help you?

Comment: I changed it to margin = 10px; but still no change. Other parts of the website with the same style applied are behaving just fine. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your body selector you left out the px after your margin size. Also since the margins are 10px all around you could write it as just margin: 10px; and then in your custom class selector you put an = instead of a colon :after margin.

Comment: I replaced the code with your edits and it still didn't work. It just doesn't make sense to me because the other parts of the same page are cooperating just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I fixed a few typos and 10px of padding

```
.wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin: 10px auto;
text-decoration-color: #356618;
background-color: white;
padding: 10px;


}



body {
margin: 10px;
background-color: #DAEAD0;
font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;


 }



 header {
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFA500;


 }



 footer {
text-align: center;
font-size: 87.5%;
background-color: #FFA500;


 }



.custom {
color: #836145;
font-size: 125%;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #8C8C8C;
margin:10px;


 }


  .custom2 {
color: #356618;
font-size: 87.5%
```

}